# Can we find out if skype is installed or not on a machine thoough web app?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I am writing some web app, from web app I want to know if skype is installed or not on a machine from which web page is called. Is this possible? if yes how?

It should work at least on Firefox, IE and chrome on windows. If it works on Linux and Mac then it will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I googled this and found https://jira.skype.com/browse/SPA-335.

Comment: Can we use javascript to read and write files on a client computer? Preferably files called `mycreditcardnumbers.txt`? It should work at least on Firefox, IE and chrome on windows. If it works on Linux and Mac then it will be great. @Prasad, are you hearing yourself what you are asking?

Comment: possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358397/javascript-to-detect-skype

Comment: @Darin: There it says there is a way to detect whether skype is installed :).

Comment: @Zaefer, no this just uses the `skype:` protocol on your browser assuming you've accepted to activate it when installing skype. For example I haven't.

Comment: @Prasad What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Note there is a Skype plugin for Firefox that will highlight phone numbers linking them to Skype if the user installs the plugin and Skype.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe you can detect this. JavaScript does not have access to machine configuration like this. [User agent strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) are the most common way for JavaScript to learn about the underlying machine, and Skype doesn't appear to publish any data there.

You can use a Java or ActiveX agent, or a plain executable, to report that data back to you (the user would have to allow that, of course), or just ask the user.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try the old trick with changed style of visited links. So if a potential user has visited [http:\skype.com](http://skype.com), chances are she's got Skype installed.

Related read: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Comment: Unless he/she has cleared the browser history or was just looking there or had someone install it from an exe.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a Java (not javascript) applet on a webpage is able to which programs are installed on the computer of someone who visits your site, although they might have to give the applet permission to run first.