# Javascript to detectSkype?

Tags: skype

I'd like to change a link's href based on that: if Skype isn't installed, show a popup explaining what Skype is and how to install it, if it is installed, change the link to skype:my.contact.name?call so the click will start a call. Real estate issues means that I'd prefer to only have one link shown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to detect Skype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358397/javascript-to-detect-skype)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, browsers do not support such API and this cannot be done cross-browser compatible way. There is some kind of support, but it is buggy.

[Javascript to detect Skype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358397/javascript-to-detect-skype?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

All browser plugins registering their mime-types in global array named `mimeTypes`, that can be accessed via navigator object `navigator.mimeTypes`.

So you can use this for check plugin active or not. If plugin installed and disabled — no any mime-type will be registred for that disabled plugin. If plugin installed and active — he has a mime-type record in `navigator.mimeTypes`

Some code implementation using jQuery:

```
jQuery.extend({checkPlugin: function(mimetype_substr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < navigator.mimeTypes.length; i++) {
        if (navigator.mimeTypes[i]['type'].toLowerCase().indexOf(mimetype_substr) >= 0) {
                console.log("Gotcha! Here it is: "+navigator.mimeTypes[i]['type']);
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}});
```

So this: `$.checkPlugin("skype");` returns `true` if skype click2call plugin is installed and active. And `false` if there is no active plugin or plugin are not installed.

Actually need to search within another global array — `navigator.plugins`, but all active plugins have their records in `navigator.mimeTypes`, and this is a bit easier.