# can't detect whether skype is installed or not on chrome using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect whether user has skype installed or not for that I am using this code but code only works for internet explorer is there any way same can be done for chrome.any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Jquery Extension

```
jQuery.extend({
    skype : function(failureFunction) {
        var $ = jQuery;

        if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) {
            return true;
        } else if ($.browser.msie) {
            try {
                if (new ActiveXObject("Skype.Detection")) return true;
            } catch(e) { }
        } else {
            if (typeof(navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-skype"]) == "object") {
                return true;
            }
        }
        $('a[href^="skype:"]').click(function() {
            failureFunction();
            return false;
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.skype(function() {
        // this function gets called if they don't have skype.
        alert("Looks like you don't have skype. Bummer.");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="skype:your.skype.username?call">Call me</a>
```

Comment: You may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358397/javascript-to-detect-skype

Comment: I have checked this but nothing works for chrome.any suggestion

Comment: One challenge is that Skype doesn't appear to install a plugin anymore, so you unlikely be able to detect it. On the Mac at least, it is simply handed off to an external application.